# jQuery ajax find data not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer-8, find

i am using jquery **submit** to post the form data.  jquery returns the Data.

in alert gets the data through ajax.

now issue is i want to display **DIV Gallery**  HTMl. for that

```
  <form action="" method="post" name="view_all" id="view_all">
  <input type="hidden" name="viewmoreimages" value="viewmore" />
  <input type="submit" value="Load more" name="viewall" id="submit"  class="b1"/>
   </form>
  <div id="gallery_cnt"></div>


 jQuery(function(){
   jQuery( "#view_all" ).submit(function( event ) {

    <?php $site_url = site_url();?>
   var viel = jQuery('#submit').val();
  jQuery.ajax({ 
     data: jQuery("form#view_all").serialize(),
     type: 'post',
     success: function(data) {

    var j = jQuery(data).find("#gallery_cnt").html(); 

    alert(j);
   jQuery('#gallery_cnt').html(j);



    }
     });
     event.preventDefault();


      });});
```

for IE8 Value of **var j** is returning **undefined** while it works fine in other browsers.

need help to display it for **ie8.**

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does it woork in ie 9 ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? To me it seems you are trying to load the remaining images for a gallery, but IMO this approach is not a good solution for that.

Comment: actully i am fetching the data from next page this page and displaying it in gallery div.   DATA returns the HTML but i want to get specific div in DATA. for that i have used FIND tag . unfortunately it doesn't work in ie8 .

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your are getting something wrong.
but try this one..

```
 <form action="" method="post" name="view_all" id="view_all">
  <input type="hidden" name="viewmoreimages" value="viewmore" />
  <input type="submit" value="Load more" name="viewall" id="submit"  class="b1"/>
   </form>
  <div id="gallery_cnt"></div>


jQuery(function(){
jQuery( "#view_all" ).submit(function( event ) 
{
    <?php $site_url = site_url();?>
    var viel = jQuery('#submit').val();
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        data: jQuery("form#view_all").serialize(),
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) 
        {
            var j = jQuery(data).find("#gallery_cnt").html(data); 
            alert(j);
            jQuery('#gallery_cnt').html(j);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Comment: Calling `jQuery.html()` with one parameter causes it to set the HTML on the specified element, instead of returning it. `j` remains undefined.